# Android apk decompilation from bat won't start

Tags: android, batch-file, decompiling

I'm trying apk tool, following the instruction I have create a folder with

[image]

Where 
-`myapp.apk` is a sample app that I want to decompile

My bat `Decompile.bat` is

```
@echo off 
pushd "%~dp0"
apktool if myapp.apk
apktool if framework-res.apk
apktool d myapp.apk
pause
```

When I start the bat the prompt autoclose after the first lines execution

```
@echo off 
apktool if myapp.apk
apktool if framework-res.apk
```

the execution of these line is correctly but jump the latet line for some reason

If I try to use apktool from prompt works, so the problem is my bat file but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Java should be in your PATH not your classpath.

Comment: Can you post your PATH parameter?

Comment: yes is in path... my mispelling

Comment: Perhaps the path you are setting (for the command window?) does not apply when you launch a .bat file from the windows GUI by clicking on it?  How about setting the path within the bat file?

Comment: Yes the problem seems that the path remains to windows folder... but I have understand how to correctly edit the bat file to avoid this

Comment: `APKTOOL` is a batch file.  Too use it from another batch file you need to prefix it with the `CALL` command. `CALL apktool if myapp.apk`

Answer (score 0):

You need to see how `apktool.bat` is referencing `java`.   I downloaded the source from github and this is what's listed:

```
@echo off
set PATH=%CD%;%PATH%;
java -jar "%~dp0\apktool.jar" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

If that's the case then it's assuming that java is in the PATH variable or in the current directory.  Maybe add an echo for the path and see why it cannot find it.  Alternatively, set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and put the full path to java inside of `apktool.bat`.

Comment: My `apktool.bat` is exactly as the code that you have posted.

Comment: If I try to use apktool from prompt, works... so the problem is my bat file... but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I have fixed the path and updated my question still cannot execute the latest line.